# Mongodb unique sparse index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose, unique, sparse-matrix

I have created a sparse and unique index on my mongodb collection.

```
var Account = new Schema({
                email: { type: String, index: {unique: true, sparse: true} },
                        ....
```

It has been created correctly:

```
{ "ns" : "MyDB.accounts", "key" : { "email" : 1 }, "name" : "email_1", "unique" : true, "sparse" : true, "background" : true, "safe" : null }
```

But if I insert a second document with a key not set I receive this error:

```
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: MyDB.accounts.$email_1  dup key: { : null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: MyDB.accounts.$email_1  dup key: { : null }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  ok: 1 }
```

Any hints?

Comment: can you check in the collection, if there is any document with 'null' for email field. It might happen that the the template engine that you are using is inserting null value for that field. I check locally, it is working fine.

Comment: By setting `email` to `unique`, it's required to be unique for every document in the collection. Only one `null` value for example. So, this it sounds like it's working as expected.

Comment: Just answered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114851/mongo-id-field-duplicate-key-error/17115770#17115770  -- it's very similar (and likely the same) issue.

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar I am using Mongoose. Apparently it seems that it doesn't create the email field because it is not present in the document. But, if I search with the command `db.collection.find({email: null})` I find one object!! It is quite strange! Any hints?

Comment: @MicheleSpina: Use mongosniff to check what are the queries coming to mongod, and see if the queries contains null email field. I am sure there has to be some new documents inserts with null email field. After that you can easily debug, who is sending those queries.

Answer (score 29):

I just had this issue too.  I wanted a value to either be null or be unique.  So, I set both the `unique` and the `sparse` flags:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
  email: {type: String, default: null, trim: true, unique: true, sparse: true},
  // ...
});
```

And, I made sure that the database had actually created the index correctly with `db.users.getIndexes();`

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
    "email" : 1
  },
  "unique" : true,
  "ns" : "test.users",
  "name" : "email_1",
  "sparse" : true,
  "background" : true,
  "safe" : null
},
```

(So, this is **not** the same as the issue here: [mongo _id field duplicate key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114851))

My mistake was setting the `default` value to `null`.  In some sense, Mongoose counts an explicit `null` as a value that must be unique.  If the field is never defined (or `undefined`) then it is not enforced to be unique.

```
email: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true, sparse: true},
```

So, if you are having this issue too, make sure you're not setting default values, and make sure you're not setting the values to `null` anywhere else in your code either.  Instead, if you need to set it explicitly, set it to `undefined` (or a unique value).

Comment: `$unset`ing the field works as well if you're transitioning from a state where the field needs to be unique to a state where you don't care about the field.

Comment: Important to note that you need to re-start the collection to make it work