# mongodb using mongoose: E11000 duplicate key error on .save with nested collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a Project entry, it has a languages array which I want to describe as

*languages can (will) be initially empty [], and each object within it must have a field called `key` which must be unique.*

e.g:

```
{
  languages: [],
  ....
}
```

or:

```
{
  languages: [ { key: 'en-US } ],
  ...
}
```

The mongoose Schema looks like:

```
{
  languages: [{
    key: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
  }],
  ...
}
```

The first creation works:

```
const project = new Project({
  name,
  owner: user,
});

await project.save();
```

However thereafter I get this error about already having a language with key: null, even though the languages array is empty...

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: yebu.projects index: tags.name_1 dup key: { : null }
    at Function.MongoError.create (<redacted>/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
...
```

I tried `sparse: true` in the key field but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

As this answer mentions: [Mongodb unique sparse index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125089/mongodb-unique-sparse-index)

The answer was to combine `unique: true` with `sparse: true`. I wasn't noticing that it was working as my next collection in the schema was failing until I added it there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - combine `unique: true`, `sparse: true` with `default: null`

```
{
  languages: [{
    key: {
      type: String,
      default: null
      unique: true,
    },
  }],
  ...
}
```