# Is it possible to create multiple "unique and sparse" indexes with Azure cosmos mongodb API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to create multiple unique indexes on `users` collection which are also sparse.

Use case: 
Allow user to signup with either phone or email

Problem:
Mongo db allows creating such indexes, and app runs as expected when connected to a real mongo 3.2 instance. However, with cosmos, email becomes a unique field but not sparse.

Is there a way to achieve this use-case with cosmos via mongodb API? i.e without resorting to check for uniqueness via a fetch query before every insert.

Attempts:
Going through cosmos' documentation didn't reveal much. They claim to support mongo 3.2 API, and sparse indexes are not mentioned in caveats. Creating a unique-sparse index with `createIndex` do not result in error, but only create a unique index. Creating another similar index on a different field doesn't give an error, but don't even create a unique index. It creates a normal index.

Update: Got a response from azure's support team:

> Currently we don’t support sparse indexes.
>   You can do this i.e. create a composite index with both the phone and email property.

I don't think a composite index is going to help me with my use case as I want both phone and email to be globally unique in the collection, not only their combination.

Answer (score -1):

Can you review this Stack Overflow  forum thread: [Mongodb unique sparse index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125089/mongodb-unique-sparse-index)

Do the following:

`var UserSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
  email: {type: String, default: null, trim: true, unique: true, sparse: true},
  // ...
});`

*Notice:*
unique: true, 
sparse: true

Comment: We're doing this same thing, and it's working in the *real* mongodb. However, problem is with CosmosDB. I want to know if this is even achievable in Cosmos because documentation is of no help.