# Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message .... duplicate key error index:

Tags: mongodb, indexing, key, duplicates

Here's my code:

When i try to work it, there's an error as it:

```
 "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message
 'localhost:27017: E11000 duplicate key error index: 
  futbol_db.maclar.$kod_1_link_1 dup key:
  { : null, : null }' in /var/www/html/cagkansokmen/futbol/db/maclar.php:182 
  Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/cagkansokmen/futbol/db/maclar.php(182):    
  MongoCollection->insert(Array) #1 {main} thrown in 
  /var/www/html/cagkansokmen/futbol/db/maclar.php on line 182"
```

The problem is about insert. Because, when i drop insert code, there's no problem about this code. But if i try to insert data, there's an error just as i said.

How can i fix it?

```
$collection1 = $db->lig_kod;
$collection_maclar = $db->maclar;
    $collection1->ensureIndex(array("kod" => 1, "link" => 1), array("unique" => true, "dropDups" => true));

    $a = $collection1->find(array())->limit(15)->skip(0);
    foreach($a as $b){
    $kod = $b["kod"];
    $link = $b["link"];

        $parc = explode(',', $link);
        $ligkoduson = $parc[0].",".$parc[1];
    $url2 = "http://www.stats.betradar.com/s4/gismo.php?&html=1&id=1424&language=tr&clientid=35&state=".$ligkoduson.",5_".$kod.",9_fixtures,231_fixtures,23_1,242_21&child=0";
        $url2 = curl($url2);
        $url2 = str_replace("\t","",$url2);
        $url2 = str_replace("\n","",$url2);
        $url2 = str_replace("\r","",$url2);

        $bul = ara("<![CDATA[", "]]>", $url2);
        $sonuc = ara("setState('", ",", $bul[0]);
        $say = count($sonuc);

        for($i = 0; $i<$say; $i++){
        $sezonbul = $sonuc[$i];

        $lonk = "http://www.stats.betradar.com/s4/gismo.php?&html=1&id=2127&language=tr&clientid=35&state=".$ligkoduson.",".$sezonbul.",9_fixtures,231_full,23_1&child=2";
        $fiksturlink = curl("http://www.stats.betradar.com/s4/gismo.php?&html=1&id=2127&language=tr&clientid=35&state=".$ligkoduson.",".$sezonbul.",9_fixtures,231_full,23_1&child=2");

        $fiksturlink = str_replace("\t","",$fiksturlink);
        $fiksturlink = str_replace("\n","",$fiksturlink);
        $fiksturlink = str_replace("\r","",$fiksturlink);

        $kategori = ara('title="', '"', $fiksturlink);
        $kategori_parcala = explode(' &gt; ', $kategori[0]);
        $tur = trim($kategori_parcala[0]);
        $ulke = trim($kategori_parcala[1]);
            $lig = $kategori_parcala[2];
            $lig_parcala = explode(' ', $lig);
            $lig_bosluk = count($lig_parcala)-1;
        $sezon = trim($lig_parcala[$lig_bosluk]);
        $lig_son = trim(str_replace($sezon, "", $lig));


            $takimlar = ara('<span class="teams">', '</a>', $fiksturlink);
            $timebul = ara('<td class="datetime">', '</td>', $fiksturlink);
            $fhbul = ara('<td class="p1 ">', '</td>', $fiksturlink);
            $ftbul = ara('<td class="nt ftx ">', '</td>', $fiksturlink);
            $dongusay = count($takimlar);
        echo $dongusay."<br>";
        for($dongu = 0; $dongu<$dongusay; $dongu++){
            $takimlarbul = ara('">', '</span>', $takimlar[$dongu]);

            $home = trim($takimlarbul[0]);
            $away = trim($takimlarbul[2]);
                $time = trim($timebul[$dongu]);
                $time_ayir = explode(' ', $time);
                $yil_ayir = explode('/', $time_ayir[0]);
                    $gun = $yil_ayir[0];
                    $ay = $yil_ayir[1];
                    $yil = $yil_ayir[2];
                $saat_ayir = explode(':', $time_ayir[1]);
                    $saat = $saat_ayir[0];
                    $dk = $saat_ayir[1];
            $time_sonuc = mktime($saat, $dk, 0, $ay, $gun, $yil);
            $fh = trim($fhbul[$dongu]);
                if(empty($fh)){
                $fh1 = null;
                $fh2 = null;
                }else{
                $fh_ayir = explode(':', $fh);
                $fh1 = $fh_ayir[0];
                $fh2 = $fh_ayir[1];
                }
            $ft = trim($ftbul[$dongu]);
            if(empty($ft)){

                $ft1 = null;
                $ft2 = null;

            }else{
                if(strpos($ft, '(')){

                    $parcala1 = explode('(', $ft);
                    $ft_ayir = explode(':', $parcala1[0]);
                    $ft1 = $ft_ayir[0];
                    $ft2 = $ft_ayir[1];

                }else{

                    $ft_ayir = explode(':', $ft);
                    $ft1 = $ft_ayir[0];
                    $ft2 = $ft_ayir[1];
                }
            }
        echo $ligkoduson."-".$sezonbul."-".$tur."-".$ulke."-".$lig_son."-".$sezon."-".$home."-".$away."-".$time_sonuc."-".$fh1."-".$fh2."-".$ft1."-".$ft2."<br>";

        $collection_maclar->insert(array(
        'ulke_kodu'=>$ligkoduson,
        'sezon_kodu'=>$sezonbul,
        'tur'=>$tur,
        'ulke'=>$ulke,
        'lig'=>$lig_son,
        'sezon'=>$sezon,
        'home'=>$home,
        'away'=>$away,
        'tarih'=>$time_sonuc,
        'fh1'=>$fh1,
        'fh2'=>$fh2,
        'ft1'=>$ft1,
        'ft2'=>$ft2
        ));
        }
        }

        }
```

Comment: From the error it seems that you are having a unique index, and you are tying to insert a second document without having those indexed fields ( i.e. 'null' is again getting inserted, for this document in the index ) causing duplicate key exception in index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongo \_id field duplicate key error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114851/mongo-id-field-duplicate-key-error)

Answer (score 0):

You have an unique index on "kod" and "link", but the document you are inserting doesn't include either of these fieldnames.

That means the first document you insert will have these values as null, and the second one will too.. but fails as it violoates the unique index you created.

Note that the "dropDupe" flag you provide with the ensureIndex() command only means "drop existing duplicates", not "if I try to use that key again, drop the previous document".

Your current code seems to be ensuring this index on the "lig_kod" collection, but I suspect you may have previously (maybe accidentally) used the $collection_maclar variable, rather then the $collection1 variable and executed the code, resulting in creating the index on the maclar collection.

-Hannes