# two identical key in one collection

Tags: mongodb

There are two identical key in one collection, what's going on ? How can I delete one of them ?

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
```

Two identical key in one collection in mongodb , here is the pic:

[image]

Comment: Does this help you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114851/mongo-id-field-duplicate-key-error

Comment: There is no unique index on the field, no index